# elasticsearch ngrams: why is shorter token matched instead of longer?

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, n-gram

I have an index with the following mapping and analyzer:

```
settings: {
    analysis: {
      char_filter: {
        custom_cleaner: {
          # remove - and * (we don't want them here)
          type: "mapping",
          mappings: ["-=>", "*=>"]
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        custom_ngram: {
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter: [ "lowercase", "custom_ngram_filter" ],
          char_filter: ["custom_cleaner"]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        custom_ngram_filter: {
          type: "nGram",
          min_gram: 3,
          max_gram: 20,
          token_chars: [ "letter", "digit" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mappings: {
    attributes: {
      properties: {
        name: { type: "string"},
        words: { type: "string", similarity: "BM25", analyzer: "custom_ngram" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have the following 2 documents in the index:

`"name": "shirts", "words": [ "shirt"]`

and

`"name": "t-shirts", "words": ["t-shirt"]`

I perform a multimatch query as

```
"query": {

            "multi_match": {
               "query": "t-shirt",
               "fields": [
                  "words",
                  "name"
               ],
               "analyzer": "custom_ngram"
            }

   }
```

**The question:**

*shirts* has a score of 1.17 whereas *t-shirt* has a score of 0.8.
Why is that and how can I achieve that *t-shirt* (the direct match) has the higher score?

I need ngrams for another use case, where I have to detect contains matches. (shirt is in muscle-shirt, ...) Therefore I can't skip the ngrams, I guess.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you are using a `StandardTokenizer`, which tokenizes the string "t-shirt" into the tokens "t" and "shirt".  "t", however, is shorter than the min gram size, and so no tokens are generated from it.  So you are getting the same matches in each case, but the document with `t-shirt` is longer, and so scores a bit lower.

You can get detailed information on why documents are getting the scores they get, by using the [Explain API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html).

Are you sure you need to use ngrams?  Your example, "shirt" in "muscle-shirt" should be handled just fine by the `StandardAnalyzer`, which will tokenize on the hyphen.

Comment: thank you for the reply!
I'll try it out in a minute.
I *think*, I need the ngrams as I want to match "muscleshirt" as well. Would that be doable without ngrams? (actually, it should match muscle-shirt and muscleshirt [sorry for the wrong example])

Comment: explain tells me, you're absolutely right.


shouldn't the char_filter strip out the - from t-shirt?
when I analyze t-shirt, elasticsearch returns ngrams without the - (tsh, shi, hir, irt, ...)

Comment: Hmm.  You're right, that doesn't quite make sense.  Can you post the explain output?

Comment: Turns out, I forgot to initialize the index with those settings, so it used the default settings... oh my... thank you for your support!